# How do I make a graph of custom json deserializers in Python

Tags: python, json

http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/05/pymotw-json.html gives a helpful introduction to the use of a hook function to control how json objects can be mapped to specific python classes.

It's not evident to me how to extend this to deeper graphs. Consider something like:

```
{
  "list_of_x": {
      "type": "x",
      "items" : [
        { "key" : "value" },
        { "key" : "value" }
      ]
  }
}
```

I want to map the outer object to one python class, and the inner objects in the list to another python class, using `JSONDecoder` and the `object_hook`. When the hook is called 'down below', how can I see the value of the `type` slot above? Or, in cases where there's no type, because there's only one possible type, how do I know where I am to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object_hook` is called *whenever a JSON object is closed*, so when the `}` character is encountered.

As such, the `object_hook` is first called for the most deeply nested objects. For your example, it'll be called for:

1. the first `{ "key" : "value" }` in the `items` list
2. the second `{ "key" : "value" }` in the `items` list
3. The `list_of_x` object, containing the `type` and `items` keys.
4. The outermost object containing the `list_of_x` key.

Because the *outer* object isn't parsed yet, there is no other context than what has been parsed so far; you'll *only* see `{u'key': u'value'}` as the argument to `object_hook` when called for the first and second times.

In step 3 and 4, the dictionary passed in will have nested container values, including whatever the earlier calls to `object_hook` have returned.

You could use heuristics here; based on the keys or the type of the values (only strings or also other containers) you can still make choices about the object types, but you'll have to do so with only the limited context passed in.

Demo:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> from itertools import count
>>> import json
>>> counter = count(1)
>>> def verbose_object_hook(dct):
...     print 'Object #{}'.format(next(counter))
...     pprint(dct)
...     return dct
... 
>>> sample = '''\
... {
...   "list_of_x": {
...       "type": "x",
...       "items" : [
...         { "key" : "value" },
...         { "key" : "value" }
...       ]
...   }
... }
... '''
>>> json.loads(sample, object_hook=verbose_object_hook)
Object #1
{u'key': u'value'}
Object #2
{u'key': u'value'}
Object #3
{u'items': [{u'key': u'value'}, {u'key': u'value'}], u'type': u'x'}
Object #4
{u'list_of_x': {u'items': [{u'key': u'value'}, {u'key': u'value'}],
                u'type': u'x'}}
{u'list_of_x': {u'items': [{u'key': u'value'}, {u'key': u'value'}], u'type': u'x'}}
```

Comment: So, the best I can do is to let it build generic dictionaries at the bottom, and repackage them into specific objects higher up -- unless I want to recreate Jackson in Python :-). Thanks.

Comment: @bmargulies: indeed; there is just not enough context available to do anything else.

Comment: It occurs to me that all of this is not really gaining very much over just letting the decoder make a graph of dicts and then post-processing it. The Java equivalent in Jackson let you get involved earlier.